# Adaptable descriptor in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-descriptors

I want to create some kind of descriptor on a class that returns a proxy object.  The proxy object, when indexed retrieves members of the object and applies the index to them.  Then it returns the sum.

E.g.,

```
class NDArrayProxy:

    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        retval = self[:]
        if dtype is not None:
            return retval.astype(dtype, copy=False)
        return retval


class ArraySumProxy(NDArrayProxy):

    def __init__(self, arrays):
        self.arrays = arrays

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.arrays[0].shape

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        return np.sum([a[indices]
                       for a in self.arrays],
                      axis=0)
```

This solution worked fine while I had actual arrays as member variables:

```
class CompartmentCluster(Cluster):

    """
    Base class for cluster that manages evidence.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.variable_evidence = ArraySumProxy([])

class BasicEvidenceTargetCluster(CompartmentCluster):

    # This class variable creates a Python object named basic_in on the
    # class, which implements the descriptor protocol.

    def __init__(self,
                 *,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.basic_in = np.zeros(self.size)
        self.variable_evidence.arrays.append(self.basic_in)

class ExplanationTargetCluster(CompartmentCluster):

    """
    These clusters accept explanation evidence.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.explanation_in = np.zeros(self.size)
        self.variable_evidence.arrays.append(self.explanation_in)

class X(BasicEvidenceTargetCluster, ExplanationTargetCluster):
    pass
```

Now I've changed my arrays into Python descriptors (`cluster_signal` implements the descriptor protocol returning a numpy array):

```
class CompartmentCluster(Cluster):

    """
    Base class for cluster that manages evidence.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.variable_evidence = ArraySumProxy([])

class BasicEvidenceTargetCluster(CompartmentCluster):

    # This class variable creates a Python object named basic_in on the
    # class, which implements the descriptor protocol.

    basic_in = cluster_signal(text="Basic (in)",
                              color='bright orange')

    def __init__(self,
                 *,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.variable_evidence.arrays.append(self.basic_in)

class ExplanationTargetCluster(CompartmentCluster):

    """
    These clusters accept explanation evidence.
    """

    explanation_in = cluster_signal(text="Explanation (in)",
                                    color='bright yellow')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.variable_evidence.arrays.append(self.explanation_in)

class X(BasicEvidenceTargetCluster, ExplanationTargetCluster):
    pass
```

This doesn't work because the append statements append the result of the descriptor call.  What I need is to append either a bound method or similar proxy.  What's the nicest way to modify my solution?  In short: The variables `basic_in` and `explanation_in` were `numpy` arrays.  They're now descriptors.  I would like to develop some version of `ArraySumProxy` that works with descriptors rather than requiring actual arrays.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  Can you show how you were using these classes before, and what has changed, and how you hope to use them after that change?

Comment: @brenbarn: Summarized.

Comment: I can't tell from your question which code was always in use and which code is new.

Comment: Your code does not show the relevant part. Is `cluster_signal` a desctiptor which has a `__get__` which returns a `numpy` array? If yes, then it behaves like a `numpy` array. And where is the old code in which `basic_in` was not defined by a descriptor?

Comment: Are you trying to get the `ArraySumProxy` to re-retrieve the arrays when indexed, perhaps because the `basic_in` and `explanation_in` attributes evaluate to different arrays on different accesses?

Comment: @user2357112 you got it!

Comment: @zvone I have clarified my question hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a descriptor, it is evaluated and you only get the value. Since your descriptor does not always return the same object (I guess you cannot avioid it?), you dont want to access the descriptor when you are initializing your proxy.

The simplest way to avoid accessing it, is to just remember its name, so instead of:

```
self.variable_evidence.arrays.append(self.basic_in)
```

you do:

```
self.variable_evidence.arrays.append((self, 'basic_in'))
```

Then, of course, `variable_evidence` has to be aware of that and do `getattr(obj, name)` to access it.

Another option is to make the descriptor return a proxy object which is evaluated later. I don't know what you are doing, but that might be too many proxies for good taste...

**EDIT**

Or... you can store the getter:

```
self.variable_evidence.arrays.append(lambda: self.basic_in)
```

Comment: Or just `lambda: self.basic_in`.

Comment: But then again, a proxy which has a getter which gets a descriptor... do you need all that?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that is better :)